# Intermittent "Invalid or corrupted PDF file" from pdf.js

Tags: php, pdf.js

I'm building a private website to share some old family letters with my relatives. To keep the letters from being crawled, I'm using a function called smartReadFile (shown below) to stream the letters to the browser. (I'll give the family a password to get into the site.) The letters are PDFs, created using a scanner.

I'm finding that some letters always display just fine, some display intermittently, and some won't display at all. All of them open just fine with Acrobat reader. When a letter fails to display, I see this message in (Firefox's) console:

```
Invalid or corrupted PDF file.
PDF.js v2.11.298 (build: d370a281c)
Message: Invalid PDF structure.
```

I've tested with both Firefox (94.0.2) and Chrome (96.0.4664.45) and while at any given time, a given letter might behave differently in one or the other, I seem the same basic problem in both. (Just went and tested with Edge, as well. Same issue.)

At the moment, this is all local to my development machine, running Windows 10 v. 21H1. The installed web server is IIS.

Here's the function, which I didn't write. (Got it from my son, who originally got it from someone else.)

```
function smartReadFile($location, $filename, $mimeType = 'application/octet-stream')
{
    if (!file_exists($location))
    {
        header ("HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found");
        return;
    }
    
    $size   = filesize($location);
    $time   = date('r', filemtime($location));
    
    $fm     = @fopen($location, 'rb');
    if (!$fm)
    {
        header ("HTTP/1.1 505 Internal server error");
        return;
    }
    
    $begin  = 0;
    $end    = $size - 1;
    
    if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_RANGE']))
    {
        if (preg_match('/bytes=\h*(\d+)-(\d*)[\D.*]?/i', $_SERVER['HTTP_RANGE'], $matches))
        {
            $begin  = intval($matches[1]);
            if (!empty($matches[2]))
            {
                $end    = intval($matches[2]);
            }
        }
    }

    if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_RANGE']))
    {
        header('HTTP/1.1 206 Partial Content');
    }
    else
    {
        header('HTTP/1.1 200 OK');
    }
    
    header("Content-Type: $mimeType"); 
    header('Cache-Control: public, must-revalidate, max-age=0');
    header('Pragma: no-cache');  
    header('Accept-Ranges: bytes');
    header('Content-Length:' . (($end - $begin) + 1));
    if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_RANGE']))
    {
        header("Content-Range: bytes $begin-$end/$size");
    }
    if($_REQUEST['SaveAs'] == "1"){
        header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=' . $filename);  
    }else{
        header("Content-Disposition: inline; filename=\"$filename\"");
    }
    header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
    header("Last-Modified: $time");
    
    $cur    = $begin;
    fseek($fm, $begin, 0);
    
    while(!feof($fm) && $cur <= $end && (connection_status() == 0))
    {
        print fread($fm, min(1024 * 16, ($end - $cur) + 1));
        $cur += 1024 * 16;
    }
}
```

My instinct is that this is about file size or a timeout or something along those lines, but I don't know how to fix it. I tried reducing the size of the chunks I'm reading and passing along (by changing the multiplier near the end of the function from 16 to 4 or 2), but no luck.

Comment: Thanks. I didn't show it, but the call to smartReadFile passes "application/PDF" as the $mimeType. Good idea to test the files with another reader. I've also considered trying to shrink them in some way because some are quite large.

Comment: Thanks for the advice about the PDFs. My intention was to trade some resolution for size (as I did years ago when I used SnagIt to reduce the size of hundreds of family photos that I'd scanned at high resolution). However, I've come to the conclusion the problem is my local web server configuration, not the files.

Answer (score 1):

At my son's advice, I tried a simplified version on a production web server (rather than my local installation) and the problem went away. So I'll put it down to some setting in my IIS installation that I don't need to figure out, and move on to finishing this project up.